# How I can remove a specific item from my ToDo list?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Can someone explain how I can remove fishing from my todolist? Thank you

```js
let TodoList = [];
const name = [];

function getReply(command) {
  const splitString = command.split(' ');
  if (command.includes('Hello') && name.length === 0) {
    //console.log(splitString);
    const grabName = splitString.slice(-1);
    name.push(grabName);
    //console.log(name);
    return 'Nice to meet you' + ' ' + grabName;
  } else if (command.includes('Hello') && name.length !== 0) {
    return 'repeted twice';
  } else if (command.includes('What is my name')) {
    return 'your name is ' + name[0];
  } else if (command.includes("my todo")) { // Add fishing to my todo and Add singing in the shower to my todo
    const task = splitString.slice(1, -3).join(' ');
    TodoList.push(task)
    return task + " added to todo list";
  }
  if (command === 'What is on todo?') {
    return TodoList;
  }
}

console.log(getReply('Hello my name is Axel')); // Nice to meet you Axel
console.log(getReply('Hello my name is Axel, Hello my name is Axel')); //Hey Axel You repeated your name twice 
console.log(getReply("Add fishing to my todo"));
console.log(getReply("Add singing in the shower to my todo"));
console.log(getReply("What is on todo?"));
console.log(getReply("**Remove fishing from my todo**"));
```

Comment: You don't need to add `<br>` to each line. Paste your code -> select it -> Click on `{}` icon in the editor ([Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bb7H.gif)). Please read: [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361) and [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 0):

Your `else if (command.includes("my todo"))` check isn’t sufficient because it matches both “Add fishing to my todo” and “Remove fishing from my todo”. Replace it by `else if (command.includes("Add") && command.includes("my todo"))`.

Now you can add the following new case, using [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). Make sure the todo item is actually on the list.

```
else if (command.includes("Remove") && command.includes("my todo")) {
  const task = splitString.slice(1, -3).join(" ");

  if(TodoList.includes("task")){
    TodoList.splice(TodoList.indexOf(task), 1);

    return task + " removed from todo list";
  }

  return task + " is not on the todo list";
}
```

---

Full code:

```js
let TodoList = [];
const name = [];

function getReply(command) {
  const splitString = command.split(" ");

  if (command.includes("Hello") && name.length === 0) {
    //console.log(splitString);
    const grabName = splitString.slice(-1);

    name.push(grabName);

    //console.log(name);
    return "Nice to meet you " + grabName;
  } else if (command.includes('Hello') && name.length !== 0) {
    return "Repeated twice";
  } else if (command.includes('What is my name')) {
    return "Your name is " + name[0];
  } else if (command.includes("Add") && command.includes("my todo")) { // Add fishing to my todo and Add singing in the shower to my todo
    const task = splitString.slice(1, -3).join(" ");

    TodoList.push(task);

    return task + " added to todo list";
  } else if (command.includes("Remove") && command.includes("my todo")) {
    const task = splitString.slice(1, -3).join(" ");
  
    if(TodoList.includes("task")){
      TodoList.splice(TodoList.indexOf(task), 1);
      
      return task + " removed from todo list";
    }
    
    return task + " is not on the todo list";
  }
  if (command === "What is on todo?") {
    return TodoList;
  }
}

console.log(getReply("Hello my name is Axel")); // Nice to meet you Axel
console.log(getReply("Hello my name is Axel, Hello my name is Axel")); // Hey Axel You repeated your name twice
console.log(getReply("Add fishing to my todo"));
console.log(getReply("Add singing in the shower to my todo"));
console.log(getReply("What is on todo?"));
console.log(getReply("Remove fishing from my todo"));
console.log(getReply("What is on todo?"));
```

Comment: Thank you much Sebastien Simon. Last question: how to get the today date by return in this function

Comment: @AxelEkamba Please don’t ask follow-up questions in comments. Usually you should [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) another question, but in this case there are [tons of resources](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+get+current+date) on that.